# Update JBoss Forge AngularJs Addon to Angular 6

Tags: angularjs, jboss, ejb, angular6, jboss-forge

I have a working AngularJs + EJB application built with JBoss Forge 2 (https://forge.jboss.org/addon/org.jboss.forge.addon:angularjs) that I need to update to Angular 6, can it be done?

JBoss Forge gives me the following structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWtKR.png)

Front and backend are built together in the same project.

I've tried using ng build on an Angular 6 example app but it does not give me that structure, it packs all my files in one, which makes it impossible to code. That structure above is great because I can edit my .js and .html on the fly without the need to build again.

Ps.: I need the app to run on JBoss 6.4 application server.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not know angular much, I didn't know about ng serve. So to answer my own question, I can just do the coding/testing with ng serve and deploy to JBoss afterwards (with the resulting files of ng build).